# Pointers, Strings and functions in C

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, c-strings

I've missed a week of class in which they covered pointers but I haven't been able to get the notes from class but my HW is due and I still don't understand how to use pointers to pass strings from function to function... below is my code in which I realize the pointers are beyond messed up but I've tried to read other forums but just get lost. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* returnInPlace(char);
int palindrom(char, char );

main(void)
{
  char newString[20];

  printf("Enter a string: ");
  scanf("%s",&newString);

  char flippedString[20]=reverseInPlace(newString);
  int palCheck= palindrome(newString, flippedString);

  if (palCheck==0)
    printf("\n\tThe reverse string is %s, so we don't have a palindrome.", flippedString);
  else
    printf("\n\tThe reverse string is %s, so we do have a palindrome.", flippedString);

}

char* reverseInPlace(char newString)
{
  int iterator;
  char flipped[20];
  char *ptr1;
  for(iterator=0;iterator<20;iterator++)
  {
    flipped[iterator]=firstString[19-iterator];
  }
  ptr1=flipped[];
  return *ptr1;
}

int palindrome(char newString, char flippedString)
{
  int iterator;
  int palCheck=1;
  for(iterator=0;iterator<20;iterator++)
  {
     if (firstString[iterator]==secondString[iterator])
      continue;
     else
     {
       palCheck=0;
       break;      
     }  
  }
  return palCheck;
}
```

Comment: what problems you are facing with this code? BTW `main(void)` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: return *ptr; means: return the value on the address that ptr contains.

Comment: there is an undefined `firststring[]`

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1**

In `char* reverseInPlace(char newString)`, you're using

```
return *ptr1;
```

which is wrong. What you may want is

```
return ptr1;
```

---

**Problem 2**

```
ptr1=flipped[];
```

is wrong. Here, you're assigning the base address of a local variable `flipped` and returning that value. `flipped` will cease to exist after `reverseInPlace()` finishes execution. You need to use dynamic memory allocation.

---

**Problem 3**

```
char flippedString[20]=reverseInPlace(newString);
```

is wrong. You cannot *assign* an array with `=` unless as initialization at time of definition.

---

**Problem 4**

```
char* reverseInPlace(char newString)
```

this function definition looks wrong by seeing the way it is being called. Maybe what you want is

```
char* reverseInPlace(char* newString)
```

instead.

*......and maybe many more. Strongly suggest to read some good book about Pointers and C basics before jumping into writing code.*

Comment: Capitalize the last p in 'problem 4' please ! :)

Comment: for Problem 3, that is the first time I am declaring that variable so that's why I assigned it, am I not allowed to do so?